# bug in gravity trigger in unity game engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started learning unity game engine from edx course , I follow step by step videos but I stuck in the following video titeld "From kinematics to physics" of course named "Introduction to video game development with Unity" , the problem is when I launch simulation gravity act as it's no plane under it , I can't figuere it

as video demonistrated , ball shouldn't fall even if gravity trigger is on[image: here is my game engine] [image: here is my code used]

Comment: It sounds like you missed something - its not overly clear (please dont post code pictures) what you expected, and what necessary settings you have set..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out , in sphere collider "is triggered" was on by default , as soon I turned it off it worked normally

Comment: is trigger is not on by default if you make a sphere and a  plane - it must be you accidentally clicked it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).